# unit testing - if record is created with certain record type

Tags: apex, unit-test, apextestrunresult

I have a function `createWithRecordTypeIfExists(String recordType)`. Its logic goes like this:

Check whether a record type for this object exists in the org.

- If yes, create a new record with this record type.
- If no, create a new record with `recordTypeId` null.

My question is: how do I unit test this logic?
Shall I do `assert` like below?

But it doesn't feel like a `unit test` anymore, too heavy and conditional embedded.

```
if(recordTypeExists()){
  //assert validate recordTypeId fetched from the org;
}else{
  //assert validate recordTypeId == null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends mainly on whether this function returns something. If so, you can write two test methods and check at the end which RT id returns, the existing one or the new one.

Comment: but the logic is still determined by whether such record type exists in the org or not. Since it is not part of my solution, there is no guarantee without referring to the record types in the org.

Comment: @XiXiao tests are usually based on assumptions. One can assume that some RT will certainly be on every environment?

Comment: the challenge is the solution was developed with unlocked package in scratch org, which doesn't have this record type, while in production or sandbox, it exists. In order to green light the test in both scenarios I need to use `if assert else assert` to check the record type existence , which feels wrong.